# How to send signed messages in BizTalk Server using WS-Security

Tags: wcf, soap, biztalk, wcf-security, ws-security

I want BizTalk to send signed  soap messages using WS-Security without encryption. 
My orchestration is using a dynamic send port. I have tried both, trying to configure a WCF-WSHttp Send Port like this:  (temporarily altered my orchestration to use this port rather than a dynamic port) as well as doing it within my orchestration.
However I only manage to get my message send out encrypted, or in plain text without being signed or encrypted.

**Configuring a Send Port.**

Result: Message gets encrypted:

[image: **enter image description here**]

**Doing it within my Message Assignment Shape:**
Result: Message gets encrypted:

```
myMessage_Request(WCF.TransportProtectionLevel)="Sign";
myMessage_Request(WCF.MessageClientCredentialType)="Certificate";
myMessage_Request(WCF.TransportClientCredentialType)="Certificate";

myMessage_Request(WCF.OpenTimeout)= "00:10:00";
myMessage_Request(WCF.CloseTimeout)= "00:10:00";
myMessage_Request(WCF.SendTimeout)= "00:10:00";
myMessage_Request(WCF.MaxReceivedMessageSize)= 2147483647;
myMessage_Request(WCF.SecurityMode)="Message";

myMessage_Request(WCF.BindingType)="customBinding";
myMessage_Request(WCF.Action)="http://MySoapAction";
myMessage_Request(BTS.Operation)=”MySoapOperation”;
myMessage_Request(WCF.ClientCertificate)="xxxxxxxx";


myPort(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Address) = http(s)://targeURI
myPort(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.TransportType) = "WCF-WSHttp";
```

If I change the above property `WCF.TransportProtectionLevel` from “`Sign`” to “`None`” the message doesn't get encrypted and also **not** signed.

Comment: I think they answered this in this thread http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6be77f3c-4266-4c92-b23e-e27189e8aa52/how-to-send-signed-messages-in-biztalk-server-using-wssecurity in that you will have to use custom bindings.