# BTS 2013 - The message has a bad message signature

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, biztalk, x509certificate

I've a problem with BizTalk Server 2013 and a WCF Service. BizTalk needs to consume the WCF Service. BizTalk needs to sign the message with a X509 certificate and I receive the following error message:

```
There was a failure executing the send pipeline: "BizTalkUtilities.SignPipeline, 
BizTalkUtilities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d749e81ab815db56" Source: 
"MIME/SMIME encoder" Send Port: "SndPort_Sign_V2" URI: "http://XXXX/DemoServiceSigned
/DemoService.svc" Reason: The message has a bad message signature.
```

First I've created the service without security, everything works. Once I've setup my security (message security, Sign) it didn't work anymore. To be sure my service was fine, I've created a test WCF client which consumes the service with the security - no problem.

The message needs to be signed using a X509 certificate. All the certificates are in the correct place. I followed the info stated on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578409.aspx).

Service config:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="clientSignConfig">
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service name="SignServiceBL.DemoService" behaviorConfiguration="DemoServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="clientSignConfig"
              contract="SignServiceBL.IDemoService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DemoServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine"/>
        </clientCertificate>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="CN=DemoServiceServerCertificate"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Client config (this works for a WCF Client, but doesn't work in BizTalk)

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="demoService_CustomBinding">
      <transactionFlow />
      <security authenticationMode="SecureConversation" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
        <secureConversationBootstrap authenticationMode="MutualSslNegotiated" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10" />
      </security>
      <textMessageEncoding />
      <httpTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>

</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="signingBehavior">
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate findValue="CN=DemoServiceSigning"
                           storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My"/>
        <serviceCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine"/>
        </serviceCertificate>
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<client>
  <endpoint address="http://XXXX/DemoServiceSigned/DemoService.svc"
      binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="demoService_CustomBinding" behaviorConfiguration="signingBehavior"
      contract="DemoService.IDemoService" name="WSHttpBinding_IDemoService">
    <identity>
      <dns value="DemoServiceServerCertificate"/>
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

I've setup tracing, but BizTalk isn't even sending a message to my service. It's like the sendpipeline is blocking my request.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

You don't need the pipeline with a MIME/SMIME encoder to sign WCF messages. You should use this pipeline if you need to sign emails... See the first sentence of [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa547244.aspx)

> *BizTalk Server supports signing outbound messages and signature verification for inbound Secure Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions (S/MIME) messages*

Once I remove the pipeline, BizTalk sends a message to the service. The problem now is that it's signed and encrypted. I am figuring out how to tell BizTalk to only sign the message. If you have any ideas, feel free to post them. If I find it, I will post it ;-)

Comment: What are the settings on your MIME/SMIME encoder?  Is the private key certificate in the Host Instance User\Personal store and configured at the BizTalk Server Group Level?

Comment: Yes, I followed the complete example of MSDN. It should work.

Comment: Have you tried using a HTTP deb-buging tool such as Fiddler to inspect the payloads being sent out from both BizTalk and your test WCF Client?  Maybe you can spot some differences there and work out what the issue is.

Comment: @ your previous comment: I need to sign WCF messages, not email messages so I don't need the MIME/SMIME encoder. I removed the pipeline and now BizTalk server signs and encrypts the message. It should only sign the message, so now I am trying to accomplish that by using a custom endpoint behavior and modify the protectionlevel of the client proxy. Is this really the way to sign a WCF message in BizTalk?

Comment: Someone else asked the same (unanswered) question but using a Dynamic send port http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570047/how-to-send-signed-messages-in-biztalk-server-using-ws-security

Comment: Stay in touch, I've found the solution and it works. I am writing a complete blogpost about it. I will post the link to the blogpost as an answer so keep in touch :-)

Comment: Well done, looking forward to seeing your solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't easy, but I was able to solve my issue :-)

I wrote a [blogpost](http://www.theintegrators.eu/biztalk-server-2013/biztalk-server-2013-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2013-linking-records-untyped-advanced/) about it, because it's a bit to complicated to create an answer here.
So check it out!