# Using BizTalk (with WCF Adapter) to consume Java service that requires WS-Security with UsernameToken and Signature

Tags: web-services, wcf, soap, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I'm trying to send a message from BizTalk 2010 to a Java web service, that's managed by a vendor (i.e I have no control over this). I have BizTalk configured to use a WCF adapter. The WS-Security requirements for the Java web service require me to send a couple security elements in the header that I can't seem to produce *at once* through BizTalk no matter what binding I use. In particular, I'm trying to generate a Signature and UsernameToken *together*.

Here's how the SOAP request should look (generated using SOAP UI, private information hidden):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <ds:Signature Id="SIG-5C3CC030C4E11C6430144952223388427" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
          <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
          <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
          <ds:Reference URI="#id-REFERENCEID">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="java" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>DigestValue</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>
          SignatureValue
        </ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-KEYID">
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-TOKENID">
            <wsse:KeyIdentifier EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">
              KeyIdentifier
            </wsse:KeyIdentifier>
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
      </ds:Signature>
      <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-TOKENID">
        <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">nonce</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>2015-12-07T21:03:53.876Z</wsu:Created>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
```

I've seen a couple articles online where people have struggled with this but it seems like the bulk of those are from around 2012. Has anyone been able to solve this / does anyone have any tips to approaching this issue?

Comment: Did you see this blog post here? http://www.scriptscoop.net/t/941fd14164f7/wcf-how-to-send-signed-messages-in-biztalk-server-using-ws-security.html  In particular Diane's answer?   You have to use customBinding and set up all the security settings manually (very painful and tedious to get right).  That same question was posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570047/how-to-send-signed-messages-in-biztalk-server-using-ws-security and here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6be77f3c-4266-4c92-b23e-e27189e8aa52/how-to-send-signed-messages-in-biztalk-server-using-wssecurity